# XmlSerializer : Remove xmlns:xsd but keep xmlns:xsi

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xsd

I'm using this method to generate an XML :

```
using (MemoryStream msRes = new MemoryStream())
        using (StreamWriter objStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(msRes))
        using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(objStreamWriter, new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true, IndentChars = String.Empty }))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(doc.GetType());
            serializer.Serialize(xw, doc);
            return msRes.ToArray();
        }
```

The result is that I have this sort of line `<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.02">`. 
I'd like to remove the attribute `xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` but keep `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.02"`.

How can I do that ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: For anyone else looking to solve this problem, check my question and its answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45589305/1292918

Answer (score 2):

You could try the below code to remove the xmlns entries:

```
var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(); ns.Add("", "");
```

Comment: Thanks but it removes all xlmns entries and I want to remove only xmlns:xsd entry.