# How to remove the xmlns:xsd attribute but keep xmlns:xsi

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, schema, xml-namespaces

I am using the .Net `XmlSerializer` to serialize an object to an XML document, in a C# Windows Forms application.

The root element should end up looking like:

```xml
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:///C:/data//MySchema.xsd">
  <!-- ... -->
</root>
```

In a partial class (to join the partial class created by `xsd.exe`), I have added the following property to add the `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` attribute.

```cs
[XmlAttribute("noNamespaceSchemaLocation", Namespace = XmlSchema.InstanceNamespace)]
public string xsiNoNamespaceSchemaLocation = @"file:///C://data//MySchema.xsd";
```

And to remove all the other namespaces, but keep the `xsi` one I have used:

```cs
XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
```

And then passed `ns` to the `XmlSerializer.Serialize()` method.

This works so far, but I'm not sure if this is correct. It feels like I'm removing what is there by default, only to try add a piece of it back again... seems like a code smell.

Maybe is there a better way that only removes the `xsd` but leaving the default `xsi`, so I don't need to add it back in again?

**Note:** There is an unanswered question on this already from some time back [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32567671/xmlserializer-remove-xmlnsxsd-but-keep-xmlnsxsi), the only suggested answer does not suit as it removes both `xsd` *and* `xsi` attributes.

Comment: What you've done looks correct to me. You can look at the internals and see that `XmlSerializer` uses [`DefaultNamespaces`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Serialization/XmlSerializer.cs,34e80c7c306a0313) when none are specified. This is why you see `xsi` and `xsd` by default.

Comment: @CharlesMager Thanks, looking at that I realised I could adjust the namespace addtion to: `ns.Add("xsi", XmlSchema.InstanceNamespace);`

Comment: @CharlesMager having read that some more it seems that your comment is spot on FWIW, if you'd like to make it an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've done looks correct to me.

You can look at the internals and see that `XmlSerializer` uses [`DefaultNamespaces`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Serialization/XmlSerializer.cs,34e80c7c306a0313) when none are specified.

This is the same as if you were to supply and `XmlSerializerNamespaces` containing prefixes / namespaces for `xsi` and `xsd` and is why you see declarations for `xsi` and `xsd` by default.

The correct thing to do to 'remove' `xsd` would be to supply an `XmlSerializerNamespaces` instance that doesn't contain that prefix / namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered a problem like you. I used `linq` first but it did not work. Later I found a better tool **XSLT**. You can use `XSLT` like [Online](http://xsltransform.net/bEzjRKm).